# Titanium: How to retrieve a running Android service?

Tags: android, service, titanium, appcelerator

I am creating an android service using this code:

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createServiceIntent({
    url : 'service.js'
});

Ti.Android.startService(intent);
```

As you can see, this service is started only once, it is not called in an interval every X milliseconds. Now when the application is exited (not put to background) and started up again, I would like to retrieve the reference of the service and stop it if the user clicks the stop button. Is there any way of achieving this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Stop a Service in app.js by
Identifying the stop button click event and call this to stop service

```
if(Ti.Android.isServiceRunning(intent){
Titanium.Android.stopService(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't stop a running service if the app was restarted as there is no reference to the 'intent'. I need to retrieve that reference somehow.

Comment: while creating the service give a reference to the service and using that reference number you can stop it

Comment: There is no reference to the intent, the app is exited and started again = no reference. The service is running all the time in the background meanwhile. I need to retrieve that reference first somehow (if possible). The problem is not to stop the running service, the problem is to get the reference to it. Unless I am misunderstanding you...

Comment: this will help you https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/android_services.js